# Data not being added in a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

i have a list of objects :

```
List<Hairdresser> HairdressersData = new List<Hairdresser>();
```

and i am using this method to add data in this list :

```
    void asyncInitState()  async {
     Hairdressercontroller HController = Hairdressercontroller();
     List<dynamic> value = await HController.GetHairdressers();
     int i = 0;
     value.forEach((dynamic entry) {

      Hairdresser p = new Hairdresser();
      p.name = value[i]["name"];
      p.location = value[i]["location"];
      this.HairdressersData.add(p);
      i++;

    });
     print("List length iniside the method : "+this.HairdressersData.length.toString());
  }
```

i am calling this method in the initState() :

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncInitState();
    print('data length is '+ this.HairdressersData.length.toString());
  }
```

the problem is thatdata is being added to the list inside the method scoop so the list length is not null however outside the method scope the list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct except, you are printing before `asyncInitState` executes completely. See [Asynchronous Programming](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Try

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    asyncInitState().then((){
      print('data length is '+ this.HairdressersData.length.toString());
    });
  }

  Future asyncInitState()  async {
     Hairdressercontroller HController = Hairdressercontroller();
     List<dynamic> value = await HController.GetHairdressers();
     int i = 0;
     value.forEach((dynamic entry) {

      Hairdresser p = new Hairdresser();
      p.name = value[i]["name"];
      p.location = value[i]["location"];
      this.HairdressersData.add(p);
      i++;

    });
     print("List length iniside the method : "+this.HairdressersData.length.toString());
  }
```

Or

```
 void initState() {
    testAsyncInitState();
    super.initState();
  }

 void testAsyncInitState() async {
    await asyncInitState();
    print('data length is '+ this.HairdressersData.length.toString());
 }
```

Comment: AsyncInitState() is of type void so it can't be populated with 'then'

Comment: HaHa...I've changed it to `Future` in my updated answer.